# How to evaluate columns in Dataframe sequentially based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a dataset like this:

```
Object1    Object2    Outcome1  Outcome2      Total_TestsObject1 Total_TestsObject2   TotalOutcomes_Object1    TotalOutcomesObject2
  A         C            0         1                    0                 0                      0                      0
  D         A            0         1                    0                 1                      0                      0
  B         E            1         0                    0                 0                      0                      0
  F         B            0         1                    0                 1                      0                      1 
  A         B            1         0                    2                 2                      1                      2  
  A         C            0         1                    3                 1                      1                      1
  D         A            0         1                    1                 4                      0                      1
  B         E            1         0                    3                 1                      1                      0
  F         B            0         1                    1                 4                      0                      2 
  A         B            1         0                    5                 5                      3                      3
```

What I would like to do is create two columns:

Column 1 tracks item in Object1 sums all it's previous unique pairs like this. TotalOutcomes_ObjectX/Total_TestsObjectX
Since an item in Object1 can previously have been in Object2 the summation must find the unique pairs in both Objects.

I know this is unclear, still trying to find a way to formulate it properly. But here is an example.

In the last row we have A & B

A's previous unique pairs closest to the event

```
A   D   row 7
A   c   row 6
```

B's previous pairs are closest to the event

```
B    F  row 9
B    E  row 8
```

So after these pairs are found the summation is as following.

```
Column 1(Object1):    Sum: (D_Outcomes + C_outcomes) / (D_TotalTest + C_TotalTest)
             = (1 + 1)/(1 + 1)=1


Column 2(Object2):    Sum: (F_Outcomes + E_outcomes) / (F_TotalTest + E_TotalTest)
             = (1 + 1)/(1 + 1)=1
```

So this process goes throu each row and find all previous unique pairs going backwards and does the summation.

How would this be done in python, I'm clueless.

```
 Input

    {
    Object1:[ A, A, B, C, A, F, B]
    Object2:[C, D, E, D, B, E, D]
    Outcome1:[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    Outcome2:[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
    TotalOutcomes_Object1:[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
    TotalOutcomes_Object2:[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
    Total_TestsObject1:[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2]
    Total_TestsObject2:[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
    }
```

Conditions:

Since an Object can be  both as an Object1 and an Object2 the summation must find the Objects's unique appearances  in both Object1 & Object2

And since the Total_Outcomes and Total_Tests are counted as Outcomes are produced and Test are conducted it must find all the unique Object pair and return their Outcomes and latest Total_Tests

```
Example:

Let's say A(Object1) and B(Object2) are a pair
A has previously been a pair with D, E and F
B has previously been a pair with C, D, G

Column1 then sums all of A's previous pair partners, meaning D, E, F
in the following way.

Sum: (D_Outcomes + E_outcomes + F_outcomes) / (C_TotalTest + D_TotalTest + F_outcomes)

Column2 then sums all of B's previous pair partners, meaning C,D, G
in the following way.

Sum: (C_Outcomes + D_outcomes + G_outcomes) / (C_TotalTest + D_TotalTest + G_outcomes)

The importance in this summations is that the pair partners latest stats are used, this is because both TotalOutcomes and TotalTest are counted up as they occur.
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `reversed` (to deal with *subsequent* instead of *previous* rows) and `cumsum` with some filter but really, it's still not clear what your exact conditions are. Please provide an example input and output, in a way that one can easily copy & paste.

Comment: Yes I understand it's still unclear, have been thinking about how to formulate the conditions properly and been facing logical problems. Alright I will try making that for you!

Comment: @a_guest added some more info, tell me if it's any helpful.